# Is there a way to ignore case when performing an xpath query

Tags: javascript, xpath

Is there a way to ignore case when performing an xpath query.
See example below.

```
//xdoc = xml document
//xdoc.outerHTML = "<Query><Filter>Test</Filter</Query>"
var strVal;

//this works - matching node is returned
var xpath = "Filter";
var result = xdoc.evaluate(xpath, xdoc, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null);
//strVal is not null
strVal = result.singleNodeValue;


//this does not
var xpath = "filter";
var result = xdoc.evaluate(xpath, xdoc, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null);
//strVal is null
strval = result.singleNodeValue;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use XPath `translate` to convert uppercase letters to lowercase.

In that case your expression would look like:

```
var xpath = '//*[translate(name(), "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz") = "filter"]';
```

There are some nicer XPath 2.0 methods like `matches` and similar, but no browser currently supports it:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_%28XML%29#Query_technologies

Here is a fiddle for the translate method:

http://jsfiddle.net/Lqw6n7ve/3/